# How can I know that a activity is opened by clicking Notification icon?

Tags: android

The UIMain can be opened by clicking either App icon or Notification icon, I hope to define which way the activity is opened.

So I set a tag using `notificationIntent.putExtra("IsStartFromIcon",true)`, but `Utility.LogError(""+isStartFromIcon)` always display **false**, what wrong with my code?

Is there the other better way? Thanks!

```
public class UIMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonClose).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PublicParFun.DisplayIconByContent(mContext, "This is OK");
                finish();
            }
        });

        boolean isStartFromIcon=this.getIntent().getBooleanExtra("IsStartFromIcon",false);
        Utility.LogError(""+isStartFromIcon);

    }

}
```

**PublicParFun.cs**

```
public class PublicParFun {
  public static void DisplayIconByContent(Context myContext,String myContentText) {

        CharSequence contentTitle= myContext.getResources().getString(R.string.NotificationTitle);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(myContext, ui.UIMain.class);

        notificationIntent.putExtra("IsStartFromIcon",true);

        PendingIntent contentItent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0,notificationIntent, 0);



        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(myContext)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(myContentText)
                .setContentIntent(contentItent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; 

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) myContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(myContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.NotificationID), notification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you

```
  private  void generateNotification(Context context, String message ) {

        int icon = R.drawable.icon;

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)

                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent;      
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("From", "notifyFrag");

        notificationIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notificationIntent .setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

}

in your activity class you can check that activity opened by Notification icon clicked or not  using below code

Inside you oncreat  you can check activity is opened by notification using

```
  String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("From");
if (type != null) {
    switch (type) {
        case "notifyFrag":

        // your activity called from notification 

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your way is the same with my way.

Comment: Let me know your result

Answer (score 0):

because you activity is running background，when you click the notifacation activity will display but intent not transfer to the activity so you cannot get the value,you can use this way:add the code `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`  this will clear the activity backgrond

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean although I invoke finish() to close the activity, the system only push the activity to background and  release it in future?

Comment: And more, is there the better way to define which way the activity is opened?

Comment: I think you may use different values of the action property in your Intent.

Comment: there is another question,your code still have a question,when you get the data,it is right but when you get another time it will repeat,you need add a param,when you create pendingintent the last param shold be `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` my way is to avoid your activity is opening and you toucg home button,activity will switch to background ,this time when you click notification the data will be wrong

Comment: And show you manifest.xml, do you have  android:launchMode="singleTop" there? Probably your Activity receives intents in onNewIntent (Intent intent).

Comment: Thanks, to ivan: I have added android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: don't forget this: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29